# Parse json using liftweb in scala with no usable value

Tags: json, scala, lift

I'm using liftweb to parse JSON from String in scala, some of record have 3 field

```
val a = {"name": "Alice", "age": 21, "job": "nurse"}
```

but some other have only 2 field

```
val b = {"name": "Bob", "age": 30}
```

I created 
case class Person(name: String, age: Long, job: String)
and when I call parse(a) it return value successfully, but when I call parse(b) it  appear exception

```
net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for algorithm
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the parameter type `job:String` you are going to have issues since that would require the parameter to have a value - and in your example it doesn't.

I'll assume we want to make that an `Option[String]` and in the example below just add multiple constructors to match your parameters. Something like this should work:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long, job: Option[String]){
  def this(name: String, age: Long) = this(name, age, None)
}
```

If you had a default value, and wanted `job` to be a `String` just change the `None` to whatever you want by default.

After that, parsing as you did above should work for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use lift-json_2.11 version **2.6.3** to fix this issue. I also came across this issue with version **3.2.0**

Comment: Can you please add a code sample that elaborates how to use that package?